# How many number of times x can be divided by y?

Tags: java, math, numbers, primes

Like x=12, it can be divided by y=2, 2 times (12/2=6, 6/2=3) and 12 can be divided by 3, 1 time and 12 can be divided by 5, 0 times.
Here x will be a composite no while y a prime number.
Is there any inbuilt function in java?

Is there any O(1) Solution?

Comment: There is no built-in function for this but you can implement one like this. This idea doesn't require more optimization as it seems to work in `O(log n)` with a simple `while` loop.

Comment: @SanketMakani is there any O(1) solution?

Comment: No, there isn't. How should this algorithm look like?

Comment: No, there is no O(1) solution, but O(n) is hardly a problem when n cannot exceed 30 anyway, and is usually around 1-3.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
  public static int howManyTimesDiv(int n, int div){
      int res=0;
      while(n%div==0){
           res++;
           n/=div;
      }
      return res;
  }

  public static void main(String[]args){
      int a=howManyTimesDiv(36, 2);
      System.out.println(a);//outputs 2
      int b=howManyTimesDiv(17, 3);
      System.out.println(b);//outputs 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is loop condition `n>0`? Either it's always true in a loop, or it's false, so it should be an `if` statement.

Comment: while n>0 is true until n/=div is bigger than 0. for in this example 36/2=18,18/2=9,9%2!=1 so it breaks the loop

Comment: If `n>0` and `n%div==0`, then `n/div` will always be `>0` too, so if `n>0` is true initially, then it'll always be true. *(assuming `div>0`)*